# How to render number/integer in axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Im trying to get the integer in the response of axios get

this is the console log

[image]

```
setDappList([response.data.stats]);

<div>{setDappList.total}</div>
```

this is not working

Answer (score 0):

You are using state setter function to access the data. i.e `setDappList`

You should use the state variable instead, in your case most probably it would by `dappList`

```
<div>{dappList.total}</div>
```

Comment: No im setting the response to setDappList, it just happens to be similar to how you would use state but its not that. Im asking how to access the integer if its not a string

Comment: i still don't understand, if you want to access any value you just access it, where it's a string or number. If you want to check the data type use `typeof setDappList.total` this will return what data type it is..

Comment: Thanks thats what i thought, i figured it out, it turns out it i had to map through response, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Its the same way as a string, i just had to map through the repsonse!